# $n$th derivative of $\frac 1{f(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there a closed-form solution for $\frac {d^n}{dx^n}\frac 1{f(x)}$? I've looked at the first five derivatives in search of some pattern, but I can't identify anything strong enough to give a closed formula.

Comment: Is $f(x)$ a particular function or its just a generalization?

Comment: @AvZ A generalization.

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly a closed form, but [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x))= \sum_{k_1 + 2k_2 + \ldots + n k_n = n} \frac{n!}{k_1!1!^{k_1}...k_n!n!^{k_n}}\left(\frac{d^{k_1 + \ldots+ k_n}}{dx^{k_1 + \ldots+ k_n}} f\right)(g(x)) \prod_j \left(\frac{d^j}{dx^j} g(x) \right)^{k_j}$$

gives

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{1}{g(x)} = \sum_{k_1 + 2k_2 + \ldots + n k_n = n} \frac{(-1)^k n!({k_1 + \ldots+ k_n})!}{k_1!1!^{k_1}...k_n!n!^{k_n}g(x)^{1+k_1 + \ldots+ k_n}} \prod_j \left({\frac{d^j}{dx^j} g(x)} \right)^{k_j}$$

Comment: Appreciated, but I was hoping for something slightly more closed.

Comment: @Laertes Aside from perhaps a recurrence relationship, I think this is the best you can hope for I'm afraid!

Comment: Small correction: The $(-1)^k$ in the second formula makes no sense because $k$ is not defined. It should read $(-1)^{k_1+\dots+k_n}$.